# Is it possible to solve $2^{x⁴} + 2^{x² - 1} \le3$ without using derivatives?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function

Using derivatives we can show that this even function is decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$ and increasing on $[0,\infty)$ has an absolute minima in $(0,-\frac32)$ . Also the function is zero only in $-1$ an $1$, so the solution of the inequation is $[-1,1]$

However, I wonder if there is an elementary (algebraic) solution for the problem.

Comment: You could just replace derivatives with simple inequalities. $x<y\implies f(x)<f(y)\implies f'(t)>0,t\in(x,y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously $f(x) = 2^{x^4}+2^{x^2-1} $ is even and it is strictly increasing for $x\geq 0$. (We use the fact that composition of two increasing functions is increasing function and a sum of two increasing functions is also increasing function.)

It is easy to guess that $x=1$ is a solution to this inequality. So each $x\in[0,1]$ is a solution. Since $f$ is even we have $x\in[-1,1]$.